# How to override .MuiSelect-nativeInput in Material-UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-selectors, jsx

```js
const styles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: { margin: "0px 20px" },
  textStyle: {
    fontFamily: "Comfortaa",
  },
  container: {},
  textField: {
    fontFamily: "Comfortaa",
  },
  dropDownFormSize: {
    width: "100%",
    fontFamily: "Comfortaa",
  },
  optionDropdown: {
    color: "black",
  },
  dropDownSelector: {
    color: "black",
    backgroundColor: "tomato",
  },
  nativeInput: {
    opacity: "1",
  },
}));

const MainTable: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = styles();
  <FormControl
    classes={{
      root: classes.dropDownFormSize,
    }}
  >
    <Select
      required
      className={classes.dropDownSelector}
      value={emotion[i]}
      name="emotion"
      onChange={handleChangeEmotion(i)}
      classes={{
        root: classes.optionDropdown,
        select: classes.optionDropdown,
        // using nativeInput here gives me error
        nativeInput: classes.nativeInput,
      }}
      MenuProps={{
        anchorOrigin: {
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left",
        },
        getContentAnchorEl: null,
        MenuListProps: {
          className: classes.optionDropdown,
        },
      }}
      placeholder="Select Something"
      native={false}
    >
      <MenuItem
        value=""
        disabled
        // className={
        //     classes.optionItems
        // }
      >
        Select Emotion
      </MenuItem>
      {emotions.map((emotion, i) => {
        return (
          <MenuItem
            key={i}
            // className={
            //     classes.optionItems
            // }
            value={emotion}
          >
            {emotion}
          </MenuItem>
        );
      })}
    </Select>
  </FormControl>;
};
```

I want to remove opacity from the `.MuiSelect-nativeInput` Class. When I try to override this class using the `nativeInput` rule, I get this error message :-
 `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'nativeInput' does not exist in type 'Partial<ClassNameMap<SelectClassKey>>'.` Eventhough, `nativeInput` rule is given in the documentation of [Select API](https://material-ui.com/api/select/). I have tried to override it in the Theme file but again, I get the error that nativeInput does not exist. How can I remove the opacity from the `MuiSelect-nativeInput` class.

[image: The nativeInput class in the HTML]
[image: Respective Class CSS]

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use a `TextField` rendered as a select input.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiSelect-nativeInput": {
      opacity: 1,
    },
  },
});

<TextField 
  select
  classes = {{ root: classes.root }}
/>
```